# html2canvas index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

Tags: html2canvas, jspdf

i have div which has high charts and table both and want to convert into to pdf using jspdf . When i am using canvas.toDataURL i am getting index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount.

Appreciate any help

Comment: i have tried to remove todataurl with canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(15,40,200,200); but still no luck .

Comment: Also have tried to implement this code from http://plnkr.co/edit/nNSvHL8MZcT6nNKg9CG9 no luck yet

Comment: OK, you add what you have tried to your question, and people will be better able to help you.  I don't know JS, but I hope you get an answer soon.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991086/how-to-display-an-image-in-two-pages-in-pdf-using-jspdf

Comment: I got this issue because the div I was trying to render had 0 width and height even though it had stuff inside it. I had to change the div to be `display: inline-block` and that got rid of the index error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the below code but getting black background in few places even though background colour is set to #FFFFFF

```
$("#btnSaveAsPDF").click(function () {
                html2canvas($("#tblSaveAsPdf_canvas"), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                var image = new Image();
                image = Canvas2Image.convertToJPEG(canvas);
                var doc = new jsPDF();
                doc.addImage(imageData, 'JPEG', 12, 10);
                var croppingYPosition = 1095;
                count = (image.height) / 1095;

                for (var i =1; i < count; i++) {
                        doc.addPage();
                        var sourceX = 0;
                        var sourceY = croppingYPosition;
                        var sourceWidth = image.width;
                        var sourceHeight = 1095;
                        var destWidth = sourceWidth;
                        var destHeight = sourceHeight;
                        var destX = 0;
                        var destY = 0;
                        var canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
                        canvas1.setAttribute('height', destHeight);
                        canvas1.setAttribute('width', destWidth);                         
                        var ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d");
                        ctx.drawImage(image, sourceX, 
                                             sourceY,
                                             sourceWidth,
                                             sourceHeight, 
                                             destX, 
                                             destY, 
                                             destWidth, 
                                             destHeight);
                        var image2 = new Image();
                        image2 = Canvas2Image.convertToJPEG(canvas1);
                        image2Data = image2.src;
                        doc.addImage(image2Data, 'JPEG', 12, 10);
                        croppingYPosition += destHeight;              
                    }                  
                var d = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace(/-/g, "");
                filename = 'report_' + d + '.pdf';
                doc.save(filename);
            }

        });
    });
```